# Abstraction is changed?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, abstract-factory

My question is, how to redesign abstract factory.

For example, I get next abstraction of vehicles:

```
interface IEngine { int Power(); }
class Gasoline : IEngine { public int Power() {return 150; }}
class Diesel : IEngine { public int Power() { return 50; }}

interface IFrame { string Name(); }
class Boxed : IFrame { public string Name() { return "Boxed frame"; }}
class Hat : IFrame { public string Name() { return "Hat frame"; }}

interface TransportFactory { 
  IEngine CreateEngine(); 
  IFrame CreateChassis(); 
}
class TrailerCar : TransportFactory { 
  public IEngine CreateEngine() { return new Diesel(); }
  public IFrame CreateChassis() { return new Boxed(); }
}
class PrivateCar : TransportFactory {
    public IEngine CreateEngine() { return new Gasoline(); }
    public IFrame CreateChassis() { return new Hat(); }
}
```

Now, I can instantiate private or trailer car.

Some one suggest me changes: engine for trailers cars can by turbo or hybrid. Only for trailers! For private car diesel and gasoline engines still usual diesel engine.
So, if i do changes:

```
public enum EngineType { Hybrid, Turbo, }

interface TransportFactory
{
    IEngine CreateEngine(EngineType t);
    IFrame CreateChassis();
}
```

and i can add classes:

```
class GasolineHybrid : IEngine
{
    public int Power()
    {
        return 70;
    }
}

class GasolineTurbo : IEngine
{
    public int Power()
    {
        return 170;
    }
}

class DieselHybrid : IEngine
{
    public int Power()
    {
        return 60;
    }
}

class DieselTurbo : IEngine
{
    public int Power()
    {
        return 98;
    }
}
```

it is good, but (!!!) private car nothing to do with it!!!
What kind of design can i use? Old abstraction get incorrect?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
class GasolineHybridTrailerCar : TransportFactory
{
    public IEngine CreateEngine()
    {
        return new GasolineHybrid();
    }
    ...
}

class GasolineTurboTrailerCar : TransportFactory
{
    public IEngine CreateEngine()
    {
        return new GasolineTurbo();
    }
    ...
}

class DieselHybridTrailerCar : TransportFactory
{
    public IEngine CreateEngine()
    {
        return new DieselHybrid();
    }
    ...
}

class DieselTurboTrailerCar : TransportFactory
{
    public IEngine CreateEngine()
    {
        return new DieselTurbo();
    }
    ...
}
```

The idea behind spawning numerous classes is to remove client's ability to do wrong choice. Since you said hybrid and turbo engines do not make sense for private cars, then keeping
    IEngine CreateEngine(EngineType t);
will require from private car factory additional efforts to refuse incorrect arguments.

I am not sure did you mean it, but class names suggest that cars are products of factory. In classic relation it will be `factory --produce--> product`. It is kinky and fun how you put it via generalization, but could be hardly recognizable by others. The beauty of patterns is that once you hear its one word name, then you feel confident about all the internals the implementation could imply.

There is pattern [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Would it be more suitable name for your design?

Comment: Classes (in your way) will be:

class *TurboGasolineTrailerCar*. Make **GasolineTurbo** object.
class *HybridGasolineTrailerCar*. Make **GasolineHybrid** object.
class *TurboDieselTrailerCar*. Make **DieselTurbo** object.
class *HybridDieselTrailerCar*. Make **DieselHybrid** object.

For me it looks abstraction problems... It looks complicated and smells bad... Does not?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my way, there should be 4 classes for trailer cars. I will edit my post

Comment: Roman, i think there should be other abstraction: before it was **Trailer** and **Private** families. Now, maybe must be **Hybrid** and **Turbo** families? Or **Gasoline** and **Diesel** families? I don't know exactly (lack of experience) which one

Comment: In my mind, it does not really matter. But we seem to share the same idea

Answer (score 0):

Remember that parameters need not be part of the interface, they can be passed to the constructor of the implementation. So you can still keep your old interface:

```
interface TransportFactory
{
    IEngine CreateEngine();
    IFrame CreateChassis();
}
```

but pass the `EngineType`to the `TrailerCar` constructor:

```
class TrailerCar : TransportFactory { 
  private readonly EngineType engineType;

  public TrailerCar(EngineType engineType)
  {
    this.engineType = engineType;
  }

  public IEngine CreateEngine()
  {
    if (engineType == EngineType.Hybrid) return new DieselHybrid();
    else return new DieselTurbo();
  }

  public IFrame CreateChassis() { return new Boxed(); }
}
```

Comment: i think it is not good idea to use constructor, different from other classes constructor. Or, maybe to use *public XXX(EngineType engineType)* constructor for all classes and change interface *interface TransportFactory*. But, as i say before, it is not relevant for private cars.
For a true, i do it now, but i hate it and i want change it.

Comment: @zzfima: The very essence of interfaces is to allow different classes with different implementations to expose the same interface. So it's perfectly fine to have different constructors for each class.

Comment: But, if it all about Abstract Factory it not will feet, probably.
Because of PrivateCar class will be without parameters:

class PrivateCar : TransportFactory 
{ 
  public PrivateCar() //No need to know the EngineType
  {
  }

  public IEngine CreateEngine()
  {
      return new GasolineTurbo(); //Returns only ONE type of engine
  }
...
}

But, it can not be implementation of:

interface TransportFactory
{
    IEngine CreateEngine(EngineType engineType);
    IFrame CreateChassis();
}

Comment: @zzfima: If you use constructor parameters, your interface will *not* have `EngineType` for `CreateEngine`, it will simply be `IEngine CreateEngine()`.